# Too few parameters. Expected 1 CSV Import

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access

I'm trying to import a CSV file to my Access database via VBA. And I'm getting this error: "Run-time error: '3061': Too few parameters. Expected 1."

I already tried adding single quotes, like the other threads suggested regarding this problem, but it didn't help.

```
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO Import (" & _
         "[Equipment]" & _
         ",[Description]" & _
         ",[User_status]" & _
         ",[Functional_Location]" & _
         ",[Functional_Location_Desc]" & _
         ",[Cost_Center]" & _
         ",[Main_WorkCtr]" & _
         ",[Manufacturer]" & _
         ",[Model_Number]" & _
         ",[Serial_Number]" & _
         ",[Plant_Section])" & _
         " SELECT Equipment,Description,User_status" & _
         ",Functional_Loc,Description3,Cost_Center,Main_WorkCtr" & _
         ",Manufacturer,Model_number,ManufSerialNo,Plant_section" & _
         " FROM [Text" & _
                ";FMT=Delimited" & _
                ";HDR=YES" & _
                ";IMEX=2" & _
                ";CharacterSet=1252" & _
                ";DATABASE=" & strFolder & "].[" & strFilename & "]"

CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
```

My CSV file's first line: Equipment,Description,User_status,Functional_Loc,Description3,Cost_Center,Main_WorkCtr,Manufacturer,Model_number,ManufSerialNo,Plant_section

[My Import Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vlYB.png)

Thanks for your help.

Mark

Comment: add `Debug.Print strSQL` before the `CurrentDB.Execute` and see if it is all right, has all the values etc.

Comment: Have you missed a square bracket on DB name?

Comment: Debug.Print: 
INSERT INTO Import ([Equipment],[Description],[User_status],[Functional_Location],[Functional_Location_Desc],[Cost_Center],[Main_WorkCtr],[Manufacturer],[Model_Number],[Serial_Number],[Plant_Section]) SELECT Equipment,Description,User_status,Functional_Loc,Description3,Cost_Center,Main_WorkCtr,Manufacturer,Model_number,ManufSerialNo,Plant_section FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;CharacterSet=1252;DATABASE=G:\GMH Emelőgépek\SAP script].[sap_adatok.csv]

Comment: Try adding single quotes around the filename. (I'm just guessing here.): `";DATABASE='" & strFolder & "'].["` so the result should be: 'DATABASE=G:\GMH Emelőgépek\SAP script']

Comment: It doesn't really have problem locating the CSV file, if I have it open I'd got a different error, saying that it needs read-write access. I tried it anyway got an error. (not a valid path)

Comment: I tried making a query to import the data also, but now I have a problem that access sets a few field to Number instead of Text (Serial Number) and I get !Num erorrs :\. 

SELECT vTbl.*
FROM
     (SELECT vCSV.*
      FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;CharacterSet=1252;DATABASE=G:\GMH Emelőgépek\SAP script].[sap_adatok.csv] As vCSV) As vTbl

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to steal vacip's answer and expand on it.  I 100% agree with his suggestion:

> add Debug.Print strSQL before the CurrentDB.Execute and see if it is
>   all right, has all the values etc.

What I would suggest is then pasting the results of Debug.Print into an Access query wizard's SQL window.  Then try to run it.  Sometimes the errors are more obvious when Access runs them through a query builder.  Also, switch over to the Design view of this new query and see if there's anything out of whack.  Usually between those two views, I can figure out any issues my query is having.

Comment: In the end I exported from SAP to excel than imported that easily instead of csv. Even after I managed to import the data Access always messed up the serial numbers because it wanted to store it as numbers, instead of text.
 Thanks for the help anyway!